# Is it possible to create a "0-by-0" matrix (or array)?

Tags: matlab

`reshape` can create both a `0-by-1` matrix and a `1-by-0` matrix:

```
>> reshape([], [0 1])
ans =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-1
>> reshape([], [1 0])
ans =
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

`reshape` can also create an *n*-dimensional *array*, for *n* > 2, in which at least one of the dimensions is 0.  For example<sup>1</sup>

```
>> reshape([], [6 0 1 2 1])
ans =
   Empty array: 6-by-0-by-1-by-2
```

But I have not managed to coax `reshape` into producing a `0-by-0` *anything* (matrix or array, that is).  For example

```
>> reshape([], [0 0])
ans =
     []
>> reshape([], [0 0 1])
ans =
     []
```

Is there any way to generate an entity that MATLAB will display interactively as a `0-by-0` matrix?

Better yet, is there a way to create an entity that MATLAB will display interactively as an *m*-by-*n array*, for any *non-negative* integers *m* and *n*?<sup>2</sup>

(My interest in this question comes from wanting to make the value returned by a function I'm writing a bit more consistent, i.e. less surprising to the user, across the range of valid input arguments.)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Note how any *trailing* dimensions of size 1 are automatically removed, as long as they appear after the second position.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> More precisely, I'm looking for an `x` such that (1) `isnumeric(x)` is `true`; (2) `numel(x)` is 0; and (3) typing `x` at the MATLAB prompt and hitting `[RETURN]` produces the *displayed output* `Empty matrix: 0-by-0` (or `Empty array: 0-by-0`).</sub>

Comment: `reshape([], [0 0])` returns `[]` which `size([])` is [ 0 0 ] - an `0-by-0` matrix. So you already get it? What are you looking for?

Comment: Also, `sparse([])` and `spalloc(0,0,0)` will display as "All zero sparse: 0-by-0" in the command window. Is a sparse empty array even more empty? ;-)

Comment: And regarding your footnote about trailing singleton dimensions, see [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/309470) and the documentation for [`ndims`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndims.html).

Comment: @thewaywewalk: I've added a second footnote that hopefully will answer your questions.

Comment: @kjo: Regarding your footnote: 3) is not possible. There is only one type of 0-by-0 arrays and that is displayed `[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` is the matlab notation for an empty 0-by-0 matrix. You created a 0-by-0 matrix, it's simply displayed in another way.

```
>> size(reshape([], [0 0]))

ans =

     0     0
```

Comment: Also `size([])` shows that `[]` is 0x0 by default, you don't even need the `reshape`

Answer (score 2):

I think `zeros(0,0)` does what you need. At least it seems to work if you interrogate it with the `size` command like so:

```
>> size(zeros(0,0))
ans =
      0     0
```